# With the TwitterAPI Python library, when you conduct a search can you filter by language?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, lang

So I am conducting a search like:

```
r = api.request('search/tweets', {'q':search_query, 
'result_type':"recent", 'count':100})
```

I know when using Tweepy you can do `lang = "en"`, but I tried searching through the TwitterAPI Docs (which are not very well documented), I couldn't find anything. Is this possible to do with TwitterAPI?

Answer (score 1):

Specifics of Twitter's API are not "well" documented in TwitterAPI's [docs](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) because the intention is for you to use Twitter's [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html). TwitterAPI is a very light wrapper around the API.

Here is the answer to your question:

```
r = api.request('search/tweets', 
                {'q':search_query, 
                 'result_type':'recent', 
                 'count':100, 
                 'lang':'en'})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options you can use on the Twitter search API - see https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

You can use `lang=` or you can restrict your search to a specific geographical area with `geocode=`